# FullCalendar get events from database

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, fullcalendar

Hi i am using FullCalendar in a laravel project and i need to display the events from the database.

I get all the events from the database and display them using json_encode.

There is the code i use :

My controller :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Gestionnaires\EventGestionnaire;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EventController extends Controller
{
    public function afficher(){

        $eventGestionnaire = new EventGestionnaire;
        $listeEvents = $eventGestionnaire->getListeEvents();

        echo json_encode($listeEvents);


        return view('pages.calendar');

    }
}
```

And my script :

```
$calendar.fullCalendar({

    viewRender: function(view, element) {
        if (view.name != 'month'){

            $(element).find('.fc-scroller').perfectScrollbar();

        }
    },

    resourceEditable: true,
    eventLimit: true,
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    header: {
        left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'prev,next,today'
    },

    events: 'EventController.php',
```

The error :

jquery.min.js:3049 GET http://localhost/planner/public/EventController.php?start=2019-09-01&end=2019-10-13&_=1568831263931 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I don't know laravel specifically but to me, in an MVC context, this looks wrong: `echo json_encode($listeEvents);


        return view('pages.calendar');` . Returning both JSON _and_ a view (i.e. some HTML) isn't going to make much sense to fullCalendar. If you want to return just the event JSON, then make a controller function which does only that, and leave a separate one to display the view containing the calendar itself

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure in laravel you don't call a controller just as "eventController.php" - again it makes no sense, how does it know which action method you want to call within the controller? I think maybe you need to take a laravel tutorial and/or read the official documentation, and make sure you understand the basics of conteollers and actions and routes, so you can set the correct URLs. Like I said I don't know that framework very well but I know enough to see that how you're using it is not the correct way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From FullCallendar V3 [DOCS](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed) to pass URL with JSON response use

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

  eventSources: [

    // your event source
    {
      url: '/myfeed.php', // use the `url` property
      color: 'yellow',    // an option!
      textColor: 'black'  // an option!
    }

    // any other sources...

  ]

});
```

Comment: I still have the same error with eventSources and the timestamp is good because when i paste in event what my database return all events are all displayed on the calendar

Comment: Maybe your PHP detects that is an ajax call and then returns an HTTP 404 for security or another reasons. Can you make a simple ajax call and log on the console the response of your URL? LIKE: if((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')) {
    http_response_code(404);
}

Comment: "I think that "events" option works with arrays" ... It can with an array, a URL, a function or an event source object. The documentation describes all these options

Comment: P.s. a 404 would not be returned for security reasons. 404 means not found. 403 or 401 are security errors

Comment: I do not agree with that, you can throw the error you want with PHP, switching 403 or 401 to an 404 will tell bots that nothing are in that link. Read: https://geekflare.com/404-instead-of-403/

Comment: Yes of course you can set whatever you like, but since OP is using a framework, the framework is likely to follow the official definition and the official definition is to use 404 for not found, not for authentication. Unless by "security" you are referring to something else than permissions?

Comment: That article you linked to is going against both common convention and the w3c spec (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), and could lead to confusing regular users as well as malicious ones, by giving them the wrong information about the problem. Besides, it is basically advocating security by obscurity, which is not a real security solution. If you have your security setup correct then such a technique should not be necessary or desirable

Comment: BTW I was talking about a possibility to his configuration, I think this is out of the scope of the initial question, refuting or making a discussion about one article, just possibilities. He gets an strange 404 huh? Why 404?

Comment: He gets a 404 because his URL is wrong. That's not how routes are accessed in an MVC framework like laravel

Answer (score 2):

I used it in the past, and using the same structure for the javascript side of it as previous answer shows. Once created your route to access it, see php code for responding to your ajax request:

```
    $results = [];

    foreach($calendar_events as $calendar_event)
    {
        $ev = [];
        $ev["title"] = $calendar_event->name;
        $ev["color"] = $calendar_event->calendar->color ?? "f47d30";

        $ev["start"] = Carbon::parse($calendar_event->start)->format("Y-m-d");
        $ev["end"]   = Carbon::parse($calendar_event->end)->format("Y-m-d");

        if (!$calendar_event->is_allday)
        {
            $ev["start"]  = Carbon::parse($calendar_event->start."T".$calendar_event->start_time)->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s");
            $ev["end"]    = Carbon::parse($calendar_event->end."T".$calendar_event->end_time)->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s");
            $ev["allDay"] = false;
        }

        if (!empty($calendar_event->url))
        {
            $ev["url"] = $calendar_event->url;
        }

        $results[] = $ev;
    }

    return response($results);
```

Comment: I used your structure and the script structure but nothing change.

Comment: But when i put the full path to url in eventSources i dont have the error 404 but Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\planner\app\Http\Controllers\GetEvent.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\planner\app\Http\Controllers\GetEvent.php on line 8